# Создание Custom View в Android

Tags: android, kotlin, customview

Начал делать свою custom view (через код, наследуясь от класса EditText (хочу сделать свой edittext под свои нужды)). Материала достаточно мало. Что посоветуйте в качестве изучения данного метода создания custom view. Может быть, есть какие-либо книги или интернет источники.

Comment: Например, [документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components) и [статья](https://tuhub.ru/posts/realizatsiya-custom-view-komponenta-v-android)

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю эта статья с примером вам поможет:
https://m.habr.com/ru/post/273589/